# Is there an R function that can reverse the Y axis in a line graph?

Tags: r, linegraph

My goal is to create a line graph showcasing:
1. Each line is one different person
2. The line plots the person's ranking over time

Since I'm trying to display ranks (eg. A person is ranked 2nd on the first month, but moves down to 4th the next month, and so on...), I would prefer the point of #1 on the Y axis to be at the top rather than at the bottom. Is that possible?

I've already created the line graph of everyone and their ranks along each timeframe, I just need a way to flip the scale of the Y axis. Thank You for your help!

Comment: Are you using base plotting functions or a package (e.g., `ggplot2`)? If you provide a reproducible example (i.e., code + data that runs as is), people can use that to demonstrate a solution.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ @Lyngbakr's advice about including the code in your post is correct. For more guidelines on what is meant by "_reproducible example_" visit this link >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this? Using scale_y_reverse

```
library(tidyverse)

ChickWeight <- ChickWeight

ggplot(ChickWeight,aes(Time,weight,group = Chick)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_reverse()
```

Comment: Do you mind marking this as an answer to you question?